# Where do we put non-database functions/library in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, directory-structure

I'm a developer who is just migrating from CodeIgniter to Laravel. In CI I had library folder where I could put non database functions, for example email verification etc. In Laravel I couldn't find something like that ? Where can I put such libraries in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is single PHP file containing different functions then you can create a Model class in your Model folder. But this Class will not extend Eloquent. It is a simple class.  For example I have a class as `General.php` containing static methods of general functionality. As Model is autoloaded so I don't need to worry about including file. It is automatically included.

But if it is a directory containing different PHP files or PHP classes then you can create a directory in your `app` directory and add the path of that directory in `providers` array in `app.php` in `config` directory. You can also create an `aliases` of your library by putting entry in `aliases` under `providers` in `app.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a library (just a folder), namespace it, and set it in config as a provider.

Then you can call it like

```
new \Foo\Class()
```